# How to get total count for each star rating?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rating

I'm using Woocommerce and I'm trying to get the total for each star rating using the post id (just like in the image below). Each rating is stored on my database as a number from 1 - 5 I just don't know how to go about retrieving the total count for each rating.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: rating system]

Comment: this is the standard Woocommerce rating ? or something else ?

Comment: I'm using standard woocommerce rating, however the image is from a plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `get_rating_count()` by specifying on each call the value needed. For example :

```
global $product;

$rating_1 = $product->get_rating_count(1);
$rating_2 = $product->get_rating_count(2);
$rating_3 = $product->get_rating_count(3);
$rating_4 = $product->get_rating_count(4);
$rating_5 = $product->get_rating_count(5);
```

You can read more about [the function](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_rating_count/)